# Can an Android App Grab CSRF Tokens from parsing web pages?

Tags: android, forms, api, token, csrf

Lets say there is a website that doesn't provide an api service. However, a legitimate android app wants to provide a useful service. So first they ask the user to create an account on that website. Then once the user is logged in, they would be able to perform certain functions like "liking" a post, or commenting on stuff, right from the app. But obviously a CSRF token is used for all form submissions. So are android apps capable of grabbing this token? If not is there a way to ask a user for permission to grab it? Also if the same app was made for iOS would the functionality work the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the app makes the login request on behalf of the user and stores the authentication cookies for use in the subsequent requests, then yes.

A `GET` request would need to be made to the web page with the form on it, the CSRF token parsed and then a `POST` request would be made passing all the required parameters (including token).

Yes this could be done with iOS too.

Comment: can you be more specific.